# object array to single array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am stuck at one point in my work. I know that it's not much more difficult but i can't find its solution now.

I am getting below result :

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
       (
          [rel_product_id] => 7
       )

   [1] => stdClass Object
        (
          [rel_product_id] => 5
        )

   [2] => stdClass Object
        (
          [rel_product_id] => 4
        )

)
```

but i want that result like :

```
$result_data = array('7','5','4');
```

can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: from where you get the result? you should share the code which retrieve the result

Comment: Please specify some relevant information like which language you are using, some code snippet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should map your array for getting the property rel_product_id of every object in it.

Below, you can see how to get that:

```
$yourarray = array(
    (object) array("rel_product_id"=>7),
    (object) array("rel_product_id"=>5),
    (object) array("rel_product_id"=>4)
);

$yourExpectedResult = array_map(create_function('$e', 'return $e->rel_product_id;'),$yourarray);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: fyi, would a closure: [Anonymous functions, also known as closures, allow the creation of functions which have no specified name.](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) be more convenient for a `one-off` task like this than creating a named function? There is nothing wrong with your code. And, if you run a version of PHP before 5.3 then that is the way to go.

Comment: That's right, for versions higher than 5.3 you could use a closure.

Comment: @Fran Carmona : hey buddy, you awesome.. exact solutions what i want . thanks :) (Y)